# combining POSIXct gives wrong hours

Tags: r, time, concatenation, posixct

I have a list of dates that I was trying to use `Reduce` on and realized that the hours were being changed when I combined the vectors. Here's an example:

```
x = structure(1315714440, tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
y = structure(1325832660, tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
x
[1] "2011-09-11 04:14:00 UTC"
y
[1] "2012-01-06 06:51:00 UTC"
c(x,y)
[1] "2011-09-11 00:14:00 EDT" "2012-01-06 01:51:00 EST"
```

Why is this happening? Any suggestions on alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: I found an old work-around using `rbind()` on the R mailing list [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-September/113895.html), in an attempt to avoid having to re-assign the time zone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c.POSIXct` removes the time zone attribute. From `?c.POSIXct`:

> Using `c` [...] on "`POSIXct`" objects drops any "`tzone`" attributes (even if they are all marked with the same time zone).

Thus, following your `c(x,y)`, you may restore the original `UTC` time zone using `attr`:

```
xy <- c(x, y)
attr(xy, "tzone") <- "UTC"
xy
# [1] "2011-09-11 04:14:00 UTC" "2012-01-06 06:51:00 UTC"
```

---

More background by Ripley here:

[c(a, b) for POSIXct objects with tzone attributes?](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-July/317789.html)

"We considered having `c()` retain the timezone if it was common to all the 
objects, but the main issue was that `c()` was documented to remove 
attributes:

> `c` is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes
>         except names, for example to turn an array into a vector.
>         `as.vector` is a more intuitive way to do this, but also drops
>         names.  Note too that methods other than the default are not
>         required to do this (and they will almost certainly preserve a
>         class attribute).

So, sometimes removing and sometimes retaining attributes was going to 
be confusing.

But in any case, the documentation (`?c.POSIXct`) is clear:

> Using `c` on "`POSIXlt`" objects converts them to the current time
>         zone, and on "`POSIXct`" objects drops any "`tzone`" attributes
>         (even if they are all marked with the same time zone).

So the recommended way is to add a "`tzone`" attribute if you know what 
you want it to be.  `POSIXct` objects are absolute times: the timezone 
merely affects how they are converted (including to character for printing)."

---

As [noted by @aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669633/combining-posixct-gives-wrong-hours/52669917#comment92269795_52669633), `rbind` can be used as work-around:

[how to retain time zone when doing c(POSIXct)](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-September/113895.html)