# Wrapping POSIXlt in a vector changes the time zone

Tags: r, vector, timezone, posixlt

I would like to create a data frame in which I have a column of POSIXlt data.

In the following way, unfortunately the time zone is lost and the time is shifted by one hour (I'm in Switzerland)

```
df <- data.frame(
  DateTime=c(
    strptime("2020-02-01T06:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = "UTC"),
    strptime("2020-02-01T06:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = "UTC")
  ),
  Name=c(
    "John",
    "Carl"
  )
)
print(df$DateTime)
```

gives:

```
[1] "2020-02-01 07:00:00 CET" "2020-02-01 07:00:00 CET"
```

The only possible workaround is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame()
df <- rbind(df,
            data.frame(DateTime=strptime("2020-02-01T06:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = "UTC"), Name="John"),
            data.frame(DateTime=strptime("2020-02-01T06:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = "UTC"), Name="Carl")
)
print(df$DateTime)
```

gives:

```
[1] "2020-02-01 06:00:00 UTC" "2020-02-01 06:00:00 UTC"
```

I have already established that the problem lies in the vector:

```
x <- strptime("2020-02-01T06:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = "UTC")
```

gives:

```
[1] "2020-02-01 06:00:00 UTC"
```

but:

```
x <- c(strptime("2020-02-01T06:00", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", tz = "UTC"))
```

gives:

```
[1] "2020-02-01 07:00:00 CET"
```

Why does wrapping the POSIXlt value in a vector changes the value itself?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; the first command returns `"2020-02-01 06:00:00 UTC"`.

Comment: Note that `?DateTimeClasses` says: *Using ‘c’ on ‘"POSIXlt"’ objects converts them to the current time
     zone, and on ‘"POSIXct"’ objects drops any ‘"tzone"’ attributes,
     unless they are all marked with the same time zone.*

Comment: Related (more focus on `POSIXct`): [Guard against accidental time-zone conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665605/guard-against-accidental-time-zone-conversion); [Odd POSIXct Function Behavior In R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489458/odd-posixct-function-behavior-in-r); [combining POSIXct gives wrong hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669633/combining-posixct-gives-wrong-hours)